# Form Help - Getting Fields to Populate from a Table with Combo Box Or Text Box Value

Tags: forms, combobox

Goal: To Create a Process Flow using forms for the Detailed Inspection for parts that are produced at my facility.

Details:

Tables - I have done a lot of work to make sure that the Database is following the Normalization rules - The Tables all have Unique Identifiers (keys) and there is little to NO duplication of information (only table I can think of that has Duplication of information is the result table where I have both the QC test listed and the results; there is also a table with JUST the QC Tests needed by part).

Forms - I have been able to successfully create a Visual Inspection Form to be completed (step 1) with a combo box that populates All Details for the Item and the Visual Inspections Needed - I am using VBA Code

`me.Field = me.Combo Box Control Source.Column(x)` to populate all 20 fields.

I am having issue with my Measurement Form - I have tried use a Similar Combo box (that the value is predetermined via `me.XXX=[Form]![Formname]![fieldname]` - however the combo box will not populate the Measurement fields using the same as above.

What I have Tried:

1) Using a Subform with the measurement form - I tried this but I wasn't able to line everything to look nice.
2) Using Dlookup directly from the Measurement table using the PartID - That didn't work. `Me.Mea1=dlookup(“[Mea1]”,”[Measurements]”,”[PartID]=”&”[PartID]”)`

Comment: Make sure you provide adequate details of the technology stack you are using along with meaningful sample code. And then add the appropriate tags so experts in that subject can find and answer your question. It also appears your question is using terminology that is very specific to your application that may be difficult for an outsider to understand that is likely irrelevant to solving the technical problem at hand

Comment: Sorry I thought that I was detailed enough and using the correct wording to make it easy to understand - only application specific wording used is for the Tables and data I am looking to have transferred.  And I have 2 tags - Forms (cause I am working with a form) and combo box - What other tags do you feel I should have added?